# "Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project have unsupported format.Please update the libraries or the plugin"

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I have installed the kotlin plugin into my android studio project.The code complies with out an issue. It also executes when I call it from a java class. It is giving me the warning "Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project have unsupported format.Please update the libraries or the plugin". The println() function is also not being recognized in the IDE.

test.kt

```
fun foo(){
    println("ad")
}



public class iTar{
   public fun printAll( vararg a: String ){
        for(item in a)println(item)
    }
}
```

Build.Gradle

```
buildscript 
{
    ext.kotlin_version = '0.8.679'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }


}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:svg-android:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: What is your version of Kotlin Plugin for Android Studio (Settings/Preferences -> Plugins -> Kotlin)?

Comment: Version 0.8.11 with android studio 0.8.6.

Comment: For Kotlin 1.0 and beyond this will no longer be an issue. the ABI version inside the class files will be the same. That is mostly true now in the betas, but there will be one more forced recompilation at the release candidate for 1.0 soon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem comes from using Kotlin 0.8.679 in your Gradle build, which is too new for the Kotlin plugin you are using in the IDE. Two possible solutions:

- update your plugin to a newer nightly build, or
- use 0.8.11 in your Gradle build

Comment: @user881269 it also fixed the issue for me (replace Kotlin version 0.8.679 by 0.8.11) on Android 0.8.9 
You should accept Andrey's answer.

Comment: how do you know **which is too new for the Kotlin plugin you are using in the IDE.**?

Comment: As a rule, you should not use the compiler version higher than your plugin version

Comment: For Kotlin 1.0 and beyond this will no longer be an issue.  the ABI version inside the class files will be the same.  That is mostly true now in the betas, but there will be one more forced recompilation at the release candidate for 1.0 soon.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleting the `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` folder. Then during the next build gradle will download again and you'll get an option to upgrade kotlin